# Styled NavLink doesn't work when imported from a file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, styled-components

I style a `NavLink` with `styled` and for some reason it works fine when the component is in he same file I want to use it. If I move it to a separate component file typescript it's throwing errors.

Here is the working code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled, { ThemeProvider, theme } from '@/theme';

const store = configureStore();

const Index = () => <h2>Home</h2>;
const Help = () => <h2>Help</h2>;

const NavigationItem = styled(NavLink)`
  color: green;

  &[aria-current] {
    color: red;
  }
`;

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router>
        <>
            <Sidebar>
              <NavigationItem to="/" exact>
                Home
              </NavigationItem>
              <NavigationItem to="/Help">Help</NavigationItem>
            </Sidebar>

            <Content>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
              <Route path="/help/" component={Help} />
            </Content>
          </AppWrapper>
        </>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```

Now, if I move `NavigationItem` in a separate file:

NavigationItem.ts

```js
import { BrowserRouter as NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from '@/theme';

const NavigationItem = styled(NavLink)`
  color: green;

  &[aria-current] {
    color: red;
  }
`;

export default NavigationItem;
```

and App.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled, { ThemeProvider, theme } from '@/theme';

const store = configureStore();

const Index = () => <h2>Home</h2>;
const Help = () => <h2>Help</h2>;

import NavigationItem from './NavigationItem';

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router>
        <>
            <Sidebar>
              <NavigationItem to="/" exact>
                Home
              </NavigationItem>
              <NavigationItem to="/help">Help</NavigationItem>
            </Sidebar>

            <Content>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
              <Route path="/help/" component={Help} />
            </Content>
          </AppWrapper>
        </>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```

I get this weird error:

```
Type '{ children: string; to: string; exact: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<BrowserRouterProps & RefAttributes<BrowserRouter>, "ref" | "basename" | "getUserConfirmation" | "forceRefresh" | "keyLength" | "key"> & Partial<...>, "ref" | ... 4 more ... | "key"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
  Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<BrowserRouterProps & RefAttributes<BrowserRouter>, "ref" | "basename" | "getUserConfirmation" | "forceRefresh" | "keyLength" | "key"> & Partial<...>, "ref" | ... 4 more ... | "key"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
```

I do not understand what is the reason for the errors as there is no difference between the two approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `NavigationItem.ts` you are using `import { BrowserRouter as NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';`

But working code `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';`

```
import { BrowserRouter as NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from '@/theme';

const NavigationItem = styled(NavLink)`
  color: green;

  &[aria-current] {
    color: red;
  }
`;

export default NavigationItem;
```

Comment: Yes, but only `NavLink` is needed for `NavigationItem.ts`. I don't see why this would cause problems.

Comment: I figured what you mean just now. This is such a stupid mistake. Thank you for pointing it out!